# Issues with LinkButton on IIS 10 / Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have recently migrated my web application to a new Server using IIS 10, and Windows Server 2016. Once I migrated my app, the **LinkButton** controls stopped working. Image Buttons, and standard buttons, however, **LinkButtons** generally do not work. The LinkButtons that seem to have the most issues are ones that simply navigate to another web page. If you could provide any suggestions as to the issue, I would much appreciate. Thank you.

Legacy version of .NET is 4.5, and this is a web application.

NOTE: Control general control syntax `<asp:LinkButton id="lnkLink" runat="server" />`

Comment: Hi Eric. Can you share a sample URI to where these LinkButtons reference?

Comment: Can you provide more info on "does not work"? Does not navigate? Not rendered correctly? Are there browser dev console errors (e.g.script)? Any other asp.net controls affected?

Comment: Sure - https://xxxxx.xxxx.xxx/Pages/Home.aspx

Comment: It does not navigate. Other LinkButtons do seem to work correctly. When I hover over the LinkButtons, it appears the ones with DoPostBackWithOptions are the most troublesome. Not sure if that's just a pattern I recognized though.

Comment: From what I can tell, there were no other .NET controls that were impacted. However, I noticed that AJAX toolkit i.e. CalendarExtender were not working as well.

Comment: `LinkButton` is rendered as `<a href="javascript:__doPostBack(...)...`. It means that JS errors on the page can damage expected behavior. Check Dev Console for errors.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev - Thank you for the reply. I admit there may be come poorly formatted JS or errors on the pages, however, the LinkButtons worked without issue on the legacy server. Any thoughts why?

Comment: FYI, found a fix - set CausesValidation to false, and that seemed to fix the issue.